# IE 7 crashes when calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have a jqGrid in my asp.net mvc 4 view and in this view I define a type that will be used for the jqGrid. The jqGrid is within a jQuery Tab (I have a jQuery tab component).

The jqGrid in the tab is inserted as follows:

```
  <div id="jqGrid">
      @Html.Partial("../Grids/_MyGrid")
  </div>
```

this is called from an ajax call in the same view as follows:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Item",
   new AjaxOptions
   {
       HttpMethod = "GET",
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
       UpdateTargetId = "jqGrid",
       OnSuccess = "showGridItems()"
   }))
{
    // My Stuff
}
```

in the same view i have defined a type that will be used for the jqGrid as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var paramFromView = {
        DeleteAllCaption: '@Resource.CaptionPagerDeleteAll',
        ClearGridUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Item/ClearGridData")',
        DeleteAllConfirmationMessage: '@Resources.Resource.ItemDeleteAllDataConfirmation',
        Url: '@Url.Content("~/Item/GetData")',
        Width: @width,
        Height: @height,
        Caption: '@Resources.Resource.ItemIndexTitle',
        ItemName: '@Resources.Resource.ItemIndexName',
        ItemAddress: '@Resources.Resource.ItemIndexAddress',
        ItemType: '@Resources.Resource.ItemIndexType',
        Actions: '@Resources.Resource.ItemIndexActions',
        PageSize: @pageSize,
    };

</script>
```

The partial view _MyGrid above indicated looks like the following also in the same view:

```
<table id="_itemGrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
</table>
<div id="_itemPager" style="text-align: center;">
</div>
```

When the ajax call is executed (see above ajax code) and the result is success, below javascript function is called onsuccess:

```
function showGridItems() {
    $('#_itemGrid').jqGrid({
        caption: paramFromView.Caption,
        colNames: ['ID', paramFromView.ItemName, paramFromView.ItemAddress, paramFromView.ItemType, paramFromView.Actions],
        colModel: (...)
}
```

This function is defined in a js file and it is included in the same view as below:

```
@section scripts
{
    @Content.Script("/Grids/ItemGrid.js", Url)
}
```

It is working perfectly in IE8, IE9 and IE10 but in IE7 it crashes in the showGridItems. The error is saying that paramFromView is not defined! I do not know why because from IE8 to IE10 is working perfectly but not for IE7. What's happening?

**UPDATED**
It was caused by the comma after the pageSize. I have removed and now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last comma (,) from the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var paramFromView = {
    DeleteAllCaption: '@Resource.CaptionPagerDeleteAll',
    ClearGridUrl: '@Url.Content("~/Item/ClearGridData")',
    DeleteAllConfirmationMessage: '@Resources.Resource.ItemDeleteAllDataConfirmation',
    Url: '@Url.Content("~/Item/GetData")',
    Width: @width,
    Height: @height,
    Caption: '@Resources.Resource.ItemIndexTitle',
    ItemName: '@Resources.Resource.ItemIndexName',
    ItemAddress: '@Resources.Resource.ItemIndexAddress',
    ItemType: '@Resources.Resource.ItemIndexType',
    Actions: '@Resources.Resource.ItemIndexActions',
    PageSize: @pageSize
};
```

Comment: Yes, it was the problem ;)

Comment: @Satpal did you say something?